# Calculation of studentized deleted residuals

Tags: self-study, residuals, t-distribution

I have a problem that asks me to calculate studentized deleted residuals from the following set of residuals:

[image: residuals]

From the original dataset:
[image]

The Hat matrix, diagonal elements hii, SSE/MSE, formula for studentized residuals, and final calculation of the residuals are below:

[image]s

[image]

However, I cannot reproduce these results given the formula! For example, taking the square root of a negative residual in the numerator results in an imaginary number if x>0. Is there another way to calculate these residuals, or something I am I just not getting it? Thanks!

Comment: The formula for the standardized (internally studentized) residual is: $r_i=e_i/\sqrt{MSE(1 - h_{ii})}$. From this, the externally studentized residuals can be calculated by: $t_i=r_i\left(\frac{n-k-2}{n-k-1-r_i^2}\right)^{(1/2)}$, where $n$ is the sample size and $k$ the number of predictors.

Answer (score 1):

The $i$-th (internally) studentized residual $r_i$ is given by
$$
r_i = \frac{e_i}{\sqrt{\mathrm{MSE}\left(1-h_{ii}\right)}},
$$
where the residual mean square $\mathrm{MSE}$ (for which a better abbreviation would be $\mathrm{MS}_{\mathrm{Res}}$) is given by $e^\top e /\left(n-p\right)$.
The $i$-th *externally* studentized residual $t_i$ is given by
$$
t_i = \frac{e_i}{\sqrt{S_{\left(i\right)}^2\left(1-h_{ii}\right)}},
$$
where $S_{\left(i\right)}^2$ is calculated as the usual unbiased estimator of the error variance but based on a data set *with the $i$-th observation removed*.

It is straightforward to show (see, e.g., Montgomery, Peck, & Vining, 2012, p. 593) that
$$
S_{\left(i\right)}^2 = \frac{\left(n-p\right)\mathrm{MSE} - e_i^2/\left(1-h_{ii}\right)}{n-p-1}.
$$
In terms of the $i$-th internally studentized residual we get
$$
\begin{align}
S_{\left(i\right)}^2 
&= \frac{\left(n-p\right)\mathrm{MSE} - r_i^2\mathrm{MSE}}{n-p-1} \\
&= \frac{\left(n-p-r_i^2\right)\mathrm{MSE}}{n-p-1},
\end{align}
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{align}
t_i 
&= \frac{e_i}{\sqrt{\frac{\left(n-p-r_i^2\right)\mathrm{MSE}}{n-p-1}\left(1-h_{ii}\right)}} \\
&= \frac{e_i}{\sqrt{\mathrm{MSE}\left(1-h_{ii}\right)}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{n-p-1}{n-p-r_i^2}} \\
&= r_i \cdot \sqrt{\frac{n-p-1}{n-p-r_i^2}}.
\end{align}
$$

---

**Reference**

Montgomery, D. C., Peck, E. A., & Vining, G. G. (2012). *Introduction to linear regression analysis* (5th ed.). John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: Lack of upvotes even though there are proper answers propel the number of unanswered questions here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is simply a typo. The formula should be:

$$
\frac{e_i}{\sqrt{\operatorname{SSE}(1-h_{ii})-e_i^2}}
$$

or similarly:

$$
\operatorname{sign}(e_i)\left[
\frac{e_i^2}{\operatorname{SSE}(1-h_{ii})-e_i^2}
\right]^{1/2}
$$

Comment: Well.... it still doesn't appear to compute the same amounts for the studentized residuals. For example, t1 should be -.424611 using your formula